# How to get name array checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="0"><span class="check">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1" ><span class="check">
```

How can I get the value through `jquery`, if I check any one of them?

Comment: I've cleaned up your question somewhat, and I think you'll benefit from showing what you've actually tried already (eg. what code have you written to try and solve your problem). I might not be able to help you but others definitely will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```js
function submit() {   
    var value = [];
    $.each($("input[name='data[]']"), function(){            
        value.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert("value: " + value.join(", "));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="0"><span class="check">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1" ><span class="check">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="submit()">
```

Comment: It's working. Please check in alert box value is displayed.

Comment: I think you write wrong in your code that's why jQuery returning undefined value.

Comment: i want to get the value by name and in input box name like data[] so how can i get the value in that case

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
          $('input[name="mails[]"]').on('submit',function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   alert(value);
});
        })   i dont want to get value in change want in submit

Comment: I think you have submit button and you get value on submit button click right...?

Comment: use data attributes to get value by name .. i guess she is trying to get by label value instead of checkbox value.

Comment: @sweta have you checked...?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(e){
    if(this.checked){
      console.log(this.value+" is checked");
    }else{
      console.log(this.value+" is un-checked");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="0"><span class="check">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1" ><span class="check">
```